# Permutation and Combination - Algebraic Expansion

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I have come across the following question and solution

Question

In how many different ways three persons A, B, C having 6, 7 and 8 one rupee coins respectively can donate Rs.10 collectively.

Solution given (http://www.askiitians.com/iit-jee-algebra/permutations-and-combinations/derangements-and-multinomial-theorem.aspx)

The number of ways in which they can denote Rs.10 is the same as the number of solutions of the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 10$ subject to conditions $0 \leq x_1 \leq 6$, $0 \leq x_2 \leq 7$, $0 \leq x_3 \leq 8$.

Hence the number of solutions is
$$
\begin{align}
&=[x^{10}](1+x+x^2+...+x^6)(1+x+x^2+...+x^7)(1+x+x^2+...+x^8)\\
&=[x^{10}]\frac{(1-x^7)(1-x^8)(1-x^9)}{(1-x)^3}\\
&=[x^{10}](1-x^7-x^8-x^9)\left(1+\binom{3}{1}x + \binom{4}{2}x^2+ \binom{5}{3}x^3+...+\binom{12}{10}x^{10}\right)\\
&= \binom{12}{10} - \binom{5}{3} - \binom{4}{2} - \binom{3}{1}\\
&= 66 - 10 - 6 - 3 = 47.
\end{align}
$$
My Doubt is how coefficient of $x^{10}$ in $(1-x^7)(1-x^8)(1-x^9)/(1-x)^3$ is equal to coefficient of $x^{10}$ in $(1-x^7-x^8-x^9)(1+\binom{3}{1}x + \binom{4}{2}x^2+ \binom{5}{3}x^3+...+\binom{12}{10}x^{10})$ ?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things at play here.

1. Expansion of $(1-x)^{-3}$. Here, we use a (negative) binomial series:
   $$
   \begin{align}
   (1-x)^{-3}&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{-3}{n}(-1)^nx^n\\
   &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-3)(-3-1)(-3-2)\cdots(-3-(n-1))}{n!}(-1)^nx^n\\
   &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n3\cdot4\cdot5\cdots(3+n-1)}{n!}(-1)^nx^n\\
   &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(n+2)_{n}}{n!}x^n\\
   &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+2}{n}x^n,
   \end{align}
   $$
   where $(a)_b$ is the *falling factorial*. Notice, here, that all terms have a non-negative power of $x$.
2. Expansion of $(1-x^7)(1-x^8)(1-x^9)$. When you multiply this out, you get
   $$
   1-x^7-x^8-x^9+x^{15}+x^{16}+x^{17}-x^{24}.
   $$

Let us combine these two results. We can think of multiplication of two such sums as the sum of terms obtained by taking one element of the first and one element of the second, and multiplying them. Since neither sum involves any negative powers of $x$, we can never choose any term from either which involves $x^{11}$ or higher - such a term can never yield an $x^{10}$. So, we find
$$
\begin{align}
&[x^{10}](1-x^7-x^8-x^9+x^{15}+x^{16}+x^{17}-x^{24})\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+2}{n}x^{n}\\
=&[x^{10}](1-x^7-x^8-x^9)\sum_{n=0}^{10}\binom{n+2}{n}x^n,
\end{align}
$$
as claimed.  From here, extracting the coefficient by $x^{10}$ should be no problem.

Comment: But (1−x)^−3 is only true when -1 < x < 1 right? can we use it here as generic expansion?

Comment: When we're dealing with generating functions, we are not viewing power series as analytical objects, but rather as purely algebraic objects. We use them as _formal power series_; convergence is of no importance.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I spent almost 10 hours on this problem and ur help is very valuable to me.

Comment: Yes thanks. I've seen too many students argue that "we only need to calculate up to $x^{13}$ because there is only a $x^3$ term in the denominator". So they get the (sometimes) correct answer for the wrong reasons.

Comment: Believe me, I've seen it too.  I should've known better than to be so sloppy!

Comment: @nrpeterson I understood the calculations u have done for $\binom{-3}{n}$ But, isn't $\binom{n}{r}$ the combination of n objects taking r at a time? if we think in this way, the value should be 0. So whay I make out is $\binom{n}{r}$ is the binomial coefficient and only when n>0, it represent the combination of n objects taking r at a time. Am I correct?

Comment: Thanks. I got the answer for my query at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination . As i understand, combinations and binomial coefficients are two different entities and both are equal only for positive integers